# redirect oauth problems in laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I am working on an SSO project that leverages Laravel Passport and Laravel UI for authentication. Additionally, I have implemented a separate client project that requests tokens from the server (as outlined in this documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#requesting-tokens). While authentication works smoothly, I noticed that the OAuth/authorize page does not automatically redirect to SSL when accessed from the client. However, I was able to fix this by modifying the URL to include HTTPS instead of HTTP. To deploy the solution, I used two Nginx proxy passes and Docker.
my first nginx conf is:

```
server {
    server_name authtest.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_pass  http://landings;
        proxy_set_header Host authtest.example.com;
    }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/auth-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/auth-access.log;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/authtest..com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/authtest..com/privkey.pem;

}
```

and second nginx inside the container is :

```
server {
    server_name authtest.naringames.com;
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen 443;
    #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root /var/www/auth/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

   }
}
```

laravel env:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

I have APP_URL to my domain but nothing changed.

Comment: Is this inside real server or local environment?

Comment: that real server